# How do I scroll back in a ubuntu live server in UTM on Mac?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, macos, gnome-terminal, arm64

I'm using Ubuntu live server through UTM on my Mac. As I listed the processes using ps command I was not able to scroll up. I have not installed the GUI since I wanted to get in touch with the terminal. Is there any way I could move up and down?

I tried control + up, shift + up, control + shift + up, options + up and fn + shift + up

Answer (score 2):

[UTM](https://mac.getutm.app/) provides only a [basic built-in terminal](https://docs.getutm.app/settings-qemu/devices/serial/#connection) with no scrolling feature.

You can configure a pseudo-TTY device, by editing the selected VM (VM needs to be shut down) in `Settings -> Serial -> Connection mode`.

You can then use the [macOS Terminal](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/terminal/welcome/mac) or [iterm2](https://iterm2.com/) and run the following command:

```
screen /dev/ttys013
```

Where `/dev/ttys013` should be the tty device displayed in the VM information panel.

You can alternatively use an SSH server inside the VM and open a session via an SSH client.

Comment: Awesome! You saved my days! Thank you!